# Is there a way to search for questions that contain images (stack.imgur or not)?

Tags: discussion, images

I ask because after seeing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/316175), in which an irrelevant image was posted (either originally or because the link had since changed), I wanted to search for more questions with images to flag any that had this problem as well. Is there some search, e.g. by url perhaps, that would narrow down the field a bit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know of a way to search for images, but finding Dropbox references is easy:

```
url:"http://dl.dropbox.com/u/*"
```

or

```
url:"http*://dl.dropbox.com/u/*"
```

Like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url:%22http*://dl.dropbox.com/u/*%22).